# File select with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, file, angular-directive, file-type

I have created the following directive to handle the file selector. It is working fine. However, I want to move all the functionality $scope.readFile() and $scope.delete() functions in the controller to be handled inside the directive itself. From the  controller, I just want to access the attachments[] array from the directive. How to implement this.

**HTML**

```
<table class="tblattach" style="width: 100%">
            <tr data-ng-repeat="a in attachments">
                <td>
                    <label class="file-label">Select File<input type="file" id="file" class="file-selector" file-selector="readFile(position, file);" index="$index" /></label>
                    <input type="text" class="tBox" data-ng-model="a.FileName" title="{{a.FileName}}" readonly />
                    <img style="vertical-align: middle;" data-ng-click="delete($index);" src="images/cancel.png" height="18" width="18" alt="Delete attachment" title="Delete current attachment" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

**DIRECTIVE**

```
myApp.directive('fileSelector', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            fileSelector: '&',
            index: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('change', function (event) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.fileSelector({ position: scope.index, file: event.target.files[0] });
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.readFile = function (position, file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function (e) {                
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.attachments[position].FileName = file.name;
                $scope.attachments[position].FileData = e.target.result;
                if ($scope.attachments.length == (position + 1))
                    $scope.attachments.push({});
            });
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    };

    $scope.delete = function (index) {
        if ($scope.attachments.length > 1)
            $scope.attachments.splice(index, 1);
        else
            $scope.attachments[0] = {};
    }
```

Comment: did you ever manage this? If so, please post it as an answer and accept eh answer (after 2 days) as this would be of help to others